# Subtracting two dates

Tags: c#, datetime, calendar, timespan

I have two calendars and each return a DateTime from calendar.SelectedDate.

How do I go about subtracting the two selected dates from each other, giving me the amount of days between the two selections?

There is a calendar.Subtract() but it needs a TimeSpan instead of DateTime.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use `someDateTime.Subtract(otherDateTime)`, this returns a `TimeSpan` which  has a `TotalDays` property.

Comment: You can also pass `Subtract()` a `TimeSpan` and it will return a `DateTime`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae6246z1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 37):

Just use:

```
TimeSpan difference = end - start;
double days = difference.TotalDays;
```

Note that if you want to treat them as *dates* you should probably use

```
TimeSpan difference = end.Date - start.Date;
int days = (int) difference.TotalDays;
```

That way you won't get different results depending on the times.

(You can use the `Subtract` method instead of the `-` operator if you want, but personally I find it clearer to use the operator.)

Comment: It's a bold man who corrects SkeetCode(tm). Good work Bhushan.

Answer (score 2):

Think about it.
How do you express a difference betwen two dates? With another date?
That's why you need the TimeSpan

```
DateTime dtToday = new System.DateTime(2012, 6, 2, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime dtMonthBefore = new System.DateTime(2012, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0);
TimeSpan diffResult = dtToday.Subtract(dtMonthBefore);
Console.WriteLine(diffResult.TotalDays);
```

Comment: Actually there are various issues with using TimeSpan to represent the difference between two dates, but in *this* case it's okay :)

Comment: Thanks for all the input. Actually I only need the day and I did not see that the Subtract method can also take a DateTime parameter meaning all I need is this: untilCalendar.SelectedDate.Subtract(fromCalendar.SelectedDate).Days

Comment: @sd_dracula: Do you definitely prefer using the `Subtract` method rather than the operator?