# Why Timespan subtract method returns error value?

Tags: c#, date, timespan

I am trying to find days between two dates using a Time span.

```
nextdate1='2014-12-20'

today    `='2014-12-18'`
```

My sample code is:

```
DateTime nexdate1 = dr.GetDateTime(2); //gets from database. I checked and the value is correct
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan nextdate = nexdate1.Subtract(today);
int difference = nextdate.Days;
```

Now I get `difference=1`. Actually the `difference is 2 (20-18)`.

Why it shows difference as 1?

Comment: What are the "time" parts of the dates? Is it saying 1 day 23 hours for example?

Comment: You're subtracting the entire DateTimes from each other instead of just the days (Note that sth. like 47 hrs will give you one day.) Try using dr.GetDateTime(2).Date and DateTime.Now.Date and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: time zones ?? "The Subtract(DateTime) method does not consider the value of the Kind property of the two DateTime values when performing the subtraction. Before subtracting DateTime objects, ensure that the objects represent times in the same time zone. Otherwise, the result will include the difference between time zones."

Comment: found this useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871755/subtracting-two-dates

Comment: @Aron, it shows only 1, no hours part and all

Comment: @SaraJohn Try looking at the `nextdate` object, not the `difference` variable

Comment: @Asad, Your last deleted comment works for me.

Comment: Change the next part in the Code: nexdate1.Subtract(today);  to  nexdate1.Date.Subtract(today.Date);  The Date property set the times to 00:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your datetime variable having time part, because of that time your result get affected. Hence you have to find only date part of your datetime value:

Use [`DateTime.Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx)

Do it like this:

```
DateTime nexdate1 = dr.GetDateTime(2);
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan nextdate = nexdate1.Date.Subtract(today.Date); // Here find only date part from datetime value.
//TimeSpan nextdate = nexdate1-today
int difference = nextdate.Days;
```

Comment: @SaraJohn Please mark suggested answer as Answer if its work for you!

Answer (score 4):

`TimeSpan.Days` is an `int`. Your answer is getting truncated.

In the following code:

```
var date1 = DateTime.Parse("Dec 12, 2014");
var date2 = DateTime.Parse("Dec 14, 2014");
var difference = (date2 - date1).Days;
```

`difference` is set to 2.

But in this code:

```
var date1 = DateTime.Parse("Dec 12, 2014 12:01 AM");
var date2 = DateTime.Parse("Dec 14, 2014");

var difference = (date2 - date1).Days;
```

`difference` is set to 1.

When we look at the timespan `date2 - date1`, we get the following:

```
{1.23:59:00}
    Days: 1
    Hours: 23
    Minutes: 59
    Seconds: 0
    TotalDays: 1.9993055555555554
```

You should set `nextDate = nexdate1.Date.Subtract(DateTime.Today);` so that you're only looking at the difference in days, or take `(int)Math.Round(nextDate.TotalDays)`

Comment: Thank you, nice description, like it