# How can i subtract a datetimepicker from current date in C# .net?

Tags: c#, datetimepicker, subtraction

```
TimeSpan result = DateTime.Today.Subtract(birthDaydateTimePicker.Value);
resultTextBox.Text = result.ToString();
```

I want the result to show as `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, your subtracting dates looks fine assuming your parameter is a date value

```
{
     TimeSpan result = DateTime.Today.Subtract(birthDaydateTimePicker.Value);
     resultTextBox.Text =  result.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

[Subtracting dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871755/subtracting-two-dates)

[Changing the format of a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649639/how-to-convert-date-format-to-dd-mm-yyyy-in-c-sharp)