# datetime not recognised in class in c#?

Tags: c#

first of all I try to make a class and then make a database via `add-migration Initial` and `update-database` .
I wrote the class below and the soustraction `DateTime.Now - SoldPr` below is didn't recognized.
Recognized means :
Argument 1 of `DateTime.Now - SoldPr` : impossible conversion of 'System.TimeSpan' to 'decimal' [Test_Dev]csharp(CS1503).

I don't know to solve this problem.

```
public class Change 
    {
            public DateTime SoldPr { get; set; }
            public int RAF{
               get
                {
                    if(SoldPr.Year > 0 )
                    {
                     return(int) Math.Floor(DateTime.Now - SoldPr).Days;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }                    
            }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please be more specific? it's quite unclear what exactly you mean by "is didn't recognized"...  please refer to [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Probably you want that **Days** to be inside the parenthesys. Subtracting two dates returns a Timespan but you can pass it to the Math.Floor. You pass a double or a decimal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subtracting two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871755/subtracting-two-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wha you probably want is:

```
return (int)Math.Floor((DateTime.Now - SoldPr).TotalDays);
```